# What is the approximate air pressure in acoustic levitation caused by the sound pressure?

Tags: waves, acoustics, levitation

I'm wondering how the sound pressure in acoustic levitation affects the actual air pressure within the standing wave. [I've read that several atmospheres of air pressure can be caused by ultrasonic transducers](https://www.quora.com/In-a-typical-ultrasound-standing-wave-for-acoustic-levitation-approximately-what-is-the-maximum-air-pressure-and-density-in-the-standing-wave-for-example-3000Pa).  However, [this paper states that up to roughly 2000Pa(RMS) of 'sound pressure' is emitted by the standing wave at its focal point:](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0097590#s1)

> The resonant frequency was 40 kHz, and the sound pressure at the peak of the focal point was as high as 2600 Pa (RMS)

Essentially, I'm trying to find out how sound pressure waves could affect the actual air pressure within the acoustic levitator and a ballpark estimate of the absolute air pressure inside the standing wave (Several atmospheres? Several KPa?).

Apologies for any mistakes in the question I am new to this exchange - any further details needed please comment and I will update/reply ASAP. Thank you for your time.